# How can I use SuiteScript 2.0 to validate Transfer Order line quantity? Script does not seem to be initializing

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

This same method has worked before to validate line level memo on an Inventory Adjustment, but for some reason this is not working. I do not believe it is initializing at all.

My goal is to validate the quantity on the line of a Transfer Order to check if the quantity is 1. If the quantity is 1, show the message (and do not let the user proceed).

Maybe it has something to do with Line Type on Transfer Orders?

```js
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType ClientScript
@NModuleScope Public
*/
define([], function () {
 function showMessage(context){
  var message = "ERROR: Do not order single units"
  var quant = context.currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
   sublistId:'item',
   fieldId:'quantity',
  });
  
  if (quant == 1) {
   alert(message);
  } 
        else {
        return true;
    }
}
 
 return {
  validateLine: showMessage
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine. Try checking your deployment record to see whether its been deployed properly (like checking role etc.)

Also, try returning false after the alert.

```
if (quant == 1) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have attempted to deploy via a deployment record (all roles) and also to add the script to a custom form. Neither have worked. No luck with adding the return false